# Assign reference to master record via constructor vs a property

Tags: apex, master-detail

Given two objects Opportunity and Project where Project is a child of Opportunity (master object), I try to assign Project to Opportunity via a property:

```
Project__c updateProject = new Project__c();
updateProject.Opportunity__c = OpportunityId;
```

When I do that, I get the error:

`FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Project__c.Opportunity__c`

However, I am able to write to this property when I pass the value via a constructor:

`Project__c updateProject = new Project__c(Opportunity__c = OpportunityId);`

I'm guessing this is because a child record must be assigned to its parent record at the time of creation.

Can someone point me to documentation that explains this behavior?

Comment: what is the relationship between opportunity and project objects? lookup or m-d?

Comment: @venky it's a master-detail relationship. I updated the question to be more concrete.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009MrpIAE
refer to the answer in this link

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot find an official documentation for this, [the answer given here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009MrpIAE) confirms my guess. (Thank you @venky.)

> If it's master-detail then, by default, you can't 'reparent' the record, that is, write to the Employee__c field after the detail record has been created. You can, however, selecting 'Allow Reparenting' in the master-detail relationship definition to make it work.

The 'Allow Reparenting' is a flag that is set on a master-detail field. By default, this field is 'false'. Hence after creating an object, you cannot assign a new parent id.

[image]